# Getting midnight of today

Tags: mysql, date

I want to get 00:00:00 of a day.  Should be done without using `CONCAT`. What options are there?

We can use `CURDATE() function` in select query but need to display like `2014-05-05 00:00:00`. If `NOW()` will give like `2014-05-05 12:05:37`.

I want add default value 00:00:00 with `CURDATE()` in query.

Answer (score 13):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) surprisigly contains a solution:

```
SELECT timestamp(current_date);
```

(which is basically the same as a [comment above](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152585/getting-midnight-of-today/152596#comment290850_152585)).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a date like `2014-05-05 12:05:37` you can use DATE_FORMAT.

```
DATE_FORMAT("2014-05-05 12:05:37", "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
```

It returns `2014-05-05 00:00:00`

Answer (score 3):

With the  MySQL functions [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and [TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(CURDATE());
```

it is the same result as

```
SELECT timestamp(current_date());
```

or even

```
SELECT timestamp(current_date);
```

> `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_DATE()` are synonyms for `CURDATE()`.

**Note:**

SQL commands are case insensitive.

Answer (score -3):

Another solution would be: cast getdate() to a date, and that back to a datetime.

Code (for MS SQL Server, but the idea applies also to mysql):

```
select cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as datetime2)
```

Comment: `getdate()` is not  a MySQL function nor is `datetime2` a valid type.

Comment: Thats why i wrote that the idea should be transferable, not the code.